# asciimath: Equation numbers

Tags: equation, asciimath

How can I get equation numbers added to asciimath:[] expression?
That is, how can I get the '(5)' in the formula such as

```
     E = m c^2                  (5)
```

Is there a method to refer to equation numbers, similar to LaTeX?